# Numpy arrays in vscode don't print past the decimal point?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I'm printing out a numpy array in VSCode's terminal that has values in the range [0,1], but when I print the array, I get the following:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]
```

I'm guessing I have to change something in `np.set_printoptions()` but I'm not exactly sure what to do

Comment: That sounds more like the array really *is* full of zeros. It's possible to see this kind of output due to misconfigured print settings, but it'd require manually configuring the print options to do this.

Comment: Yup, turns out code had some bugs in it, thanks for your help!